# Indicator functions and vector spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following is an exercise I have encountered in my linear algebra exercise book (I will not provide the reference as it is an Italian one). The solution was attached to it; still, as it is the first time I encounter the indicator function, I am unsure about its understanding.

Consider the vector space $ℝ^{[0,1]}$ and its subset $S=\{1_{[0,2^{-n}]} : n \in \mathbb N_0\}$, where $1_A$ is the indicator function of $A$.
Let $W = \operatorname{span}(S)$ and consider the function $g := 1_{(\frac12, 1]}$.

> **Question**: Does $g$ belong to $W$?

**Solution:** Yes, indeed $g$ can be rewritten as $$g = 1_{[0,1]} - 1_{[0,\frac12]}$$

**My reasoning:** Since we have to rewrite $g$ as an element of $W$, the lower end of the interval where the indicator function is defined must be equal to $0$. To do so, we exploit the fact that the interval $[0,1]$ can be decomposed as $$[0,1] = [0,\tfrac12] \cup (\tfrac12,1].$$

Yet, I think I have an issue with the full understanding of how an indicator function works. For example, in our case, when is $g(x)$ equal to 1? When $x∈[0,1]$ or when $x∈[0,\tfrac12]$?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: The notation isn't clear, at least not to me.  What is "the vector space $\mathbb R[0,1]$"?  I also can't sort out of you are putting brackets into subscripts or supercripts for a reason or if it is just bad formatting.  Can you clarify?

Comment: $g = 1_{(\frac{1}{2},1]}$, so $g(x) = 1$ when $x \in (\frac{1}{2},1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are interested in how an indicator function works. I think the following clarification may help.

**Definition.** Let $A$ be a subset of $[0,1]$, then
the indicator function is defined as follows
\begin{align}
\mathbf 1_A(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, \text{ if } x\in A\\
0, \text{ if } x\notin A
\end{cases}
\end{align}

**Back to your problem**,
\begin{align}
g(x)=\mathbf 1_{(0.5,1]}(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, \text{ if } x\in (0.5,1]\\
0, \text{ if } x\in [0,0.5]
\end{cases}
\end{align}

We now prove that $g=\mathbf 1_{[0,1]}-\mathbf 1_{[0,0.5]}$. Indeed,

- If $x\in (0.5,1]$, then $\mathbf 1_{[0,1]}(x)-\mathbf 1_{[0,0.5]}(x)=1-0=1=g(x)$.
- If $x\in [0,0.5]$, then $\mathbf 1_{[0,1]}(x)-\mathbf 1_{[0,0.5]}(x)=1-1=0=g(x)$.

---

**My comments.**

- *Regarding the notation $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$.* It is well known that $\mathbb R^n$ is the vector space in which each vector has $n$ components. Similarly, $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$ is the vector space in which each vector has "$[0,1]$ components", in other words, $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$ is the space of function over $[0,1]$.
- *Regarding your resoning.* To prove that $g\in span(S)$, you should rewrite $g$ as a combination of elements in $S$. Notice that $S$ contains the set of the form $[0,2^{-n}]$, thus you should use
  \begin{align}
  [0,1]\setminus [0,0.5]=(0.5,1]
  \end{align}
  and then we have
  \begin{align}
  \mathbf 1_{[0,1]}-\mathbf 1_{[0,0.5]}=\mathbf 1_{(0.5,1]}=g.
  \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a set, and $S$ a subset of $X$, the indicator function $\mathbf 1_S : X \to \mathbb R$ is $1$ in $S$ and $0$ elsewhere, that is, for each $x \in X$ we have
$$\mathbf 1_S(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \textrm{if } x \in S, \\[0.3mm]
0 & \textrm{if } x \notin S. \end{cases}$$

Now, if $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $X$, the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{A  \cup B}$ is the same as $\mathbf 1_A+\mathbf 1_B-\mathbf 1_{A \cap B}$. This is because for $x \in A \cup B$ we have three cases: $(1)$ $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$; $(2)$ $x \in B$ and $x \notin A$; $(3)$ $x \in A \cap B$. In the first case we have $$\mathbf 1_{A  \cup B}(x) = 1 = 1+0-0 = \mathbf 1_A(x)+\mathbf 1_B(x)-\mathbf 1_{A \cap B}(x),$$
in the second case we have
$$\mathbf 1_{A  \cup B}(x) = 1 = 0+1-0 = \mathbf 1_A(x)+\mathbf 1_B(x)-\mathbf 1_{A \cap B}(x),$$ and in the third case we have
$$\mathbf 1_{A  \cup B}(x) = 1 = 1+1-1 = \mathbf 1_A(x)+\mathbf 1_B(x)-\mathbf 1_{A \cap B}(x).$$
Also, if $x \notin A \cup B$ then $\mathbf 1_A(x)+\mathbf 1_B(x)-\mathbf 1_{A \cap B}(x) = 0+0-0 = 0 = \mathbf 1_{A  \cup B}(x)$.

Thus $\mathbf 1_{A  \cup B} = \mathbf 1_A+\mathbf 1_B-\mathbf 1_{A \cap B}$, and in particular, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint ($A \cap B = \varnothing$) we have that $\mathbf 1_{A  \cup B} = \mathbf 1_A+\mathbf 1_B$. Hence, in your problem $X = [0,1]$ and $[0,1] = [0,\tfrac12] \cup (\tfrac12,1]$ tells us that $$\mathbf 1_{[0,1]} = \mathbf 1_{[0,\frac12]} + \mathbf 1_{(\frac12,1]} \implies 1_{(\frac12,1]} = \mathbf 1_{[0,1]} - \mathbf 1_{[0,\frac12]}.$$